# Sort vector of file names in R as windows would sort them?

Tags: r, sorting, character

I want to sort a vector of file names in R, just like how Windows sorts them when sorting by name (right-click --> sort by --> name).

Let's say I have four jpg files (I have more). Windows, when sorting by name, sorts them in a order as I've written below:

`283_20200110_230606.jpg`
`500_20191203_032950.jpg`
`10889_20200114_165958.jpg`
`314368230_20200116_140854.jpg`

R when using `list.files()`, would sort them like this:
`"10889_20200114_165958.jpg"     "283_20200110_230606.jpg"       "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg" "500_20191203_032950.jpg"`

It seems in R `character`, the number 1 always comes first, whereas Windows compares the numbers before the first underscore.

Is there a way to make them sorted in the same way? Either sort in R as Windows would, or sort in Windows as R does?

**EDIT:**

data  for testing:

`v1 <- c("10889_20200114_165958.jpg",    "283_20200110_230606.jpg",       "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg", "500_20191203_032950.jpg")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
gtools::mixedsort(v1)
#[1] "283_20200110_230606.jpg"       "500_20191203_032950.jpg"       "10889_20200114_165958.jpg"    
#[4] "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("283_20200110_230606.jpg", "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg", 
"500_20191203_032950.jpg", "10889_20200114_165958.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[0-9]{1,}` will extract any number of digits 0-9 preceding the `_` break in the vector of file names. Converting to a numeric, and sorting gives you the desired order.

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- c("283_20200110_230606.jpg", "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg", 
       "500_20191203_032950.jpg", "10889_20200114_165958.jpg")

tibble(f) %>% 
  mutate(prefix = as.numeric(str_extract(f, "[0-9]{1,}"))) %>% 
  arrange(prefix) %>% 
  pull(f)

[1] "283_20200110_230606.jpg"      
[2] "500_20191203_032950.jpg"      
[3] "10889_20200114_165958.jpg"    
[4] "314368230_20200116_140854.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Rtools installed then:

```
shell("dir/b | C:\\Rtools\\bin\\sort.exe -g", intern = TRUE)
```

or if you have wsl installed:

```
shell('wsl ls -1 | sort -g', intern = TRUE)
```

Note that if the natural order happens to be the order in which the files were created you could just do this:

```
shell("dir/b /od", intern = TRUE)
```